# Swagger UI 3.4.5 npm run buld cannot pass

Tags: typescript, webpack, swagger

I have a problem with swagger-ui-dist building. I have modified ./src/standalone/index.js file and wanted to build project but I get some webpack (uglify?) errors.

```
mlabno@mlabno-Vostro-3800 ~/www/swagger-ui-new $ npm run build
> swagger-ui@3.0.17 build /home/mlabno/www/swagger-ui-new
> npm run build-core && npm run build-bundle && npm run build-standalone


> swagger-ui@3.0.17 build-core /home/mlabno/www/swagger-ui-new
> webpack --config webpack-dist.config.js --colors
Hash: 25aa5b47fe02ae228bad
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 1670ms
   [0] multi swagger-ui 52 bytes {0} [built]
    + 57 hidden modules

ERROR in swagger-ui.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (deepExtend) [./src/core/index.js:1,7]
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
        + 2 hidden modules

> swagger-ui@3.0.17 build-bundle /home/mlabno/www/swagger-ui-new
> webpack --config webpack-dist-bundle.config.js --colors

Hash: 72cc91c23fbcd6c7392e
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 710ms
   [0] multi swagger-ui-bundle 40 bytes {0} [built]
    + 56 hidden modules

ERROR in swagger-ui-bundle.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (deepExtend) [./src/core/index.js:1,7]

> swagger-ui@3.0.17 build-standalone /home/mlabno/www/swagger-ui-new
> webpack --config webpack-dist-standalone.config.js --colors

Hash: f3098a23b08f46354297
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 630ms
   [0] multi swagger-ui-standalone-preset 40 bytes {0} [built]
    + 56 hidden modules

ERROR in swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (StandaloneLayout) [./src/standalone/index.js:1,7]
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Fixed log formatting

Comment: Ok, I have downloaded swagger again and built it and now everything is working fine.